# How are anonymous types initialized with LINQ to Entities?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

LINQ to entities support anonymous type as return type, such as:

```
var query = from a in b.C select new { Value = a.Value };
```

and code generated by the compiler will be something like:

```
private class f__AnonymousType0<j__TPar>
{
    private readonly j__TPar i__Field;
    public j__TPar Value
    {
        get { return i__Field; }
    }

    public f__AnonymousType0(j__TPar Value)
    {
        i__Field = Value;
    }
}
```

But if I use the generated anonymous type instance:

```
var query = from a in b.C select new f__AnonymousType0<string>(a.Value);
```

error:

```
System.NotSupportedException: Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities.
```

will be thrown.

So how did anonymous type work here?

Comment: You're probably trying to inject the `a.Value` in the ctor (via the parentheses), but you should use object initializer brackets (`{}`)

Comment: Where did you get `f__AnonymousType0` from? How is the constructor called at that place?

Comment: @bump but the field and property are both readonly

Comment: @Patrick Hofman use ILSpy or other .NET Decompiler, check IL code, then "translate" to C# code. Refer to [Why are anonymous types generic](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/12/20/why-are-anonymous-types-generic/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the compiler has to *execute* an anonymous type initializer, then it ends up calling the constructor. But in LINQ to Entities - or any other `IQueryable`-based LINQ provider - the code isn't actually executed... it's just converted into an expression tree.

So in your sample here:

```
var query = from a in b.C select new { Value = a.Value };
```

... that will be converted into a call to [`Expression.New`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549042(v=vs.110).aspx) which effectively represents the anonymous type initializer. Crucially (I believe), it creates a `NewExpression` with the [`Members`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.newexpression.members(v=vs.110).aspx) property set to indicate that the `Value` property was initialized from the first argument to the constructor.

I expect that LINQ to Entities analyzes that `NewExpression` to work out what your original code meant, and infer what it needs to do to turn it into SQL. It can't do that with just a constructor call.

Comment: I somehow missed your explanation for `Members` and posted my own answer. Indeed it's crucial, and my sample with the custom type just confirms that EF has no special treatment of anonymous type, so I guess you can remove the last paragraph. P.S. I've deleted my post since all it does was to confirm the other parts of yours. I guess `Members` property was specifically added to support anonymous type construction, but practically can be utilized by expression building libraries like AutoMapper. Looking forward to see if and how C#7 tuple support will be added to the expression trees.

Comment: @IvanStoev: Thanks, will delete the last part.